# Python multiprocessing merge dictionaries of dictionaries from multiple processes

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shared-memory, shared

I am trying to use shared memory across multiple processes to update a dictionary that contains dictionaries which contain dictionaries...  I tried using the Manager from the multiprocessing module, but I am having difficulty adding a dictionary to it.  Please see the code and the comments below.  Essentially this code is supposed to create a copy of the input in another dictionary called "output."  Once I get this working, there will be logic to only copy certain "blades" from the input, but the node/cluster/blade hierarchy must be maintained.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Manager

# Define dictionary that will be used in this example
input = {
    "Node_1": {
        "IP": "127.0.0.1", 
        "clusters": {
            "cluster_1": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_1": "127.0.1.1", 
                    "blade_0_2": "127.0.1.2"
                }
            }, 
            "cluster_2": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_3": "127.0.1.3", 
                    "blade_0_4": "127.0.1.4"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "Node_2": {
        "IP": "127.0.0.2", 
        "clusters": {
            "cluster_1": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_1": "127.0.1.1", 
                    "blade_0_2": "127.0.1.2"
                }
            }, 
            "cluster_2": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_3": "127.0.1.3", 
                    "blade_0_4": "127.0.1.4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def iterate_over_clusters_in_node(input, node, lock, output):
    """ Iterate over the clusters in the node, then over the blades in the cluster.  Add each blade to the output dictionary."""
    for cluster in input[node]['clusters']:
        for blade in input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades']:
            with lock:
                print "node: " + node + ", node_IP: " + input[node]['IP'] + ", cluster: " + cluster + ", Blade: " + blade + ", cluster_IP: " + input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]
            with lock:
                add_blade_to_output(input, node, cluster, blade, output)

def add_blade_to_output(input, node, cluster, blade, output):
    ''' Adds a blade to the managed output dictionary'''
    if node not in output:
        output[node] = {}
        output[node]['IP'] = input[node]['IP']
        output[node]['clusters'] = {}
    # At this point, I would expect output[node]['IP'] and output[node]['clusters'] to exist
    # But the following print raises KeyError: 'IP'
    print output[node]['IP']
    if cluster not in output[node]['clusters']:
        # Raises KeyError: 'clusters'
        output[node]['clusters'][cluster] = {}
        output[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'] = {}
    output[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade] = input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create lock to ensure correct handling of output from multiple processes
    lock = Lock()

    # Create dictionary to hold any failed blades so that appropriate measures can be taken
    # Must use a Manager so that the dictionary can be shared among processes
    manager = Manager()
    output = manager.dict()

    # Create array to track our processes
    procs = []

    # Iterate over all nodes in input
    for node in input: 
        p = Process(target = iterate_over_clusters_in_node, args = (input, node, lock, output))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    # Join processes and wait for them to stop
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print "The final output is:"
    print output
    # Expectation: should print the same dictionary as the input
    # Actual: prints "{'Node_2': {}, 'Node_1': {}}"
```

Do I need to be adding manager.dict() to output[node] instead of the built-in dictionary type?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: I am not against switching this to a "threading" implementation instead of "multiprocessing."  I'm new to running things in parallel, so if threading is better suited for this type of memory sharing, please let me know.

Edit: Here is the working code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Manager

# Define dictionary that will be used in this example
input = {
    "Node_1": {
        "IP": "127.0.0.1", 
        "clusters": {
            "cluster_1": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_1": "127.0.1.1", 
                    "blade_0_2": "127.0.1.2"
                }
            }, 
            "cluster_2": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_3": "127.0.1.3", 
                    "blade_0_4": "127.0.1.4"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    "Node_2": {
        "IP": "127.0.0.2", 
        "clusters": {
            "cluster_1": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_1": "127.0.1.1", 
                    "blade_0_2": "127.0.1.2"
                }
            }, 
            "cluster_2": {
                "blades": {
                    "blade_0_3": "127.0.1.3", 
                    "blade_0_4": "127.0.1.4"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Create dictionary to hold any failed blades so that appropriate measures can be taken
# Must use a Manager so that the dictionary can be shared among processes
manager = Manager()
output = manager.dict()

def iterate_over_clusters_in_node(input, node, lock):
    """ Iterate over the clusters in the node, then over the blades in the cluster.  Add each blade to the output dictionary."""
    for cluster in input[node]['clusters']:
        for blade in input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades']:
            with lock:
                add_blade_to_output(input, node, cluster, blade)

def add_blade_to_output(input, node, cluster, blade):
    ''' Adds a blade to the managed output dictionary'''
    if node not in output:
        new_node = {}
        new_node[node] = {'IP': input[node]['IP'], 'clusters': {}}
        output.update(new_node)
    new_node = {}
    new_node.update(output)
    if cluster not in output[node]['clusters']:
        new_node[node]['clusters'][cluster] = {}
        new_node[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'] = {blade: input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]}
    else:
        new_node[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade] = input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]
    output.update(new_node)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create lock to ensure correct handling of output from multiple processes
    lock = Lock()

    # Create array to track our processes
    procs = []

    # Iterate over all nodes in input
    for node in input: 
        p = Process(target = iterate_over_clusters_in_node, args = (input, node, lock))
        p.start()
        procs.append(p)

    # Join processes and wait for them to stop
    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print "The final output is:"
    print output
```

Comment: If you can upgrade to Python v3.6 and use dict and list proxies you should be able to get it to work - https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#proxy-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the python docs,

> Modifications to mutable values or items in dict and list proxies will
>   not be propagated through the manager, because the proxy has no way of
>   knowing when its values or items are modified. To modify such an item,
>   you can re-assign the modified object to the container proxy.

With this information, we can update the manager accordingly:

```
#output[node] = {}
#output[node]['IP'] = input[node]['IP']
#output[node]['clusters'] = {} These changes are not propagated through the manager

new_node = {}
new_node[node] = {'IP': input[node]['IP'], 'clusters': {}}
output.update(new_node)



#if cluster not in output[node]['clusters']:
    # Raises KeyError: 'clusters'
    #output[node]['clusters'][cluster] = {}
    #output[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'] = {}
    #output[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade] = input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]


node_copy = output.copy()
if cluster not in node_copy[node]['clusters']:
    node_copy[node]['clusters'].setdefault(cluster, {'blades': {}})
node_copy[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade] = input[node]['clusters'][cluster]['blades'][blade]
output.update(node_copy)
```

#### References

- [Notice about value propagation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.list)